# Timer increases memory usage in C# app

Tags: c#, timer

I'm making a C# win form app (VS2010, .NET4) that uses a timer, my interval is 1s, I track task manager and it seems that my memory usage (the value written in front of app name in process tab of task manager) increases by each interval! I do nothing special in timer tick event, just increase an integer variable and display it in a label.

Is it normal? Should I be concerned about this memory problem? I'm going to run this program in my server (through remote desktop), would it cause any problems to my server? Would it run out of memory?
I use timer from VS toolbox.

Comment: Can you post some code about how you invoke the timer and what the timer does on its `ElapsedEventHandler` event?

Comment: Did you try running the `Profiler` and see if this is really the issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's take the following example which updates a label every second with the current time:

```
var timer = new Timer
{
    Interval = 1000,
};
timer.Tick += (s, evt) =>
{
    label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
};
timer.Start();
```

If you have code like this you shouldn't be worried about memory usage. The garbage collector could run at any time in order to free memory. It's just that you cannot determine when this happens.

Comment: +1 on Darin's comment.  As long as you aren't doing anything to hang onto the memory long term you should be fine.  The GC will clean it up if it needs it.  At each tick, you'll create a new string instance for the label text and new event args in the least.  These should be recycled when needed by the CLR and aren't worth concern.

Answer (score 1):

Just for debugging, try forcing a garbage collection by running

```
GC.Collect();
```

Your memory usage should go back down to approximately where it was.  By the way -- you can do this in the debugger by evaluating that expression in quick watch.